Creating an account_id from a pallet for custom proxy-like logic
I want to create an AccountId that can have balance sent to it, but has specific application logic meant for it in a pallet. Basically, a way for multiple accounts to share one account with custom logic without using smart contracts.
Say I have a pallet but want to have multiple accounts that abide by the pallet logic but these accounts all share the same logic. I hope that makes sense.
I found in the proxy pallet a way to create a new AccountId: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/033d4e86cc7eff0066cd376b9375f815761d653c/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs#L613
My question:
Is it possible for this generated AccountId to be duplicated in any possible way? I only want the pallet logic to dictate what this AccountId tokens can do.

These parts are not clear:

Basically, a way for multiple accounts to share one account with custom logic without using smart contracts.


Say I have a pallet but want to have multiple accounts that abide by the pallet logic but these accounts all share the same logic. I hope that makes sense.


Custom logic from the logic of the pallet. Basically I want to be able to create an AccountId on the fly from within a pallet. I do believe the proxy pallet part I linked does this. I just have the concern that would this Account be accessible in any way from a wallet?
